# QGIS API : Split a first polyline layer by a second points layer

Tags: pyqgis, splitting

Is QGIS or the API QGIS able to split a first polyline shape layer by a second points shape layer as show in the figure bellow.

Is this possible?

The goal is to calculate segments length between points.
The points are positioned exactly on the polyline.
In this example, there would be 3 segments.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can use difference provided by the module processing in pyQGIS

```
diff = processing.runalg("qgis:difference", line_layer, point_layer, False, None)
result = processing.getObject(diff['OUTPUT'])
```

with result as a line vector layer

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this method return a polyline vector layer exactly the same as the input polyline vector layer.

Comment: @QuentinR that's maybe because your points are not overlapping the polylines, try to apply a small buffer on them then proceed with the difference algorithm

Comment: The points layer is created from intersection process so points are overlapping the polyline. I have try to moove them one the polyline with the snapping option and the result is the same (original polyline).

Answer (score 2):

There is currently a feature request for the addition of a "Split lines with points layer" tool:

[Feature request #5040](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/5040)

---

Another method is to use the **networks** plugin which can be installed from the menubar:

```
Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins
```

Once installed, you can use the *Connect* tool:

```
Vector > Networks > Connect
```

This connects your points to the nearest line feature and splits it.

[image: Connect points]

[image: Result]

*Note that your line feature may contain duplicate features after the split.*

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this plugin does the job well manually, but now I want to integrate it into my own plugin

Comment: @QuentinR - Most welcome! You should probably either [ask a new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) or [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/250296/edit) your question to include more details as to what you are needing help with as you mentioned either "QGIS or the QGIS API" and not specifically for a plugin. You could look at the source code for the plugin and check how the `Connect` function works.